# Is it possible to use the AWS api to create Cloudwatch graphs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to create graphs programmatically in a Cloudwatch dashboard using the AWS API or a SDK?

**Edit** I'd like to use the API to create Metric and Text widgets in the Cloudwatch Dashboard. I do not want to manually create each graph.

Comment: Are you asking about creating/defining items in a dashboard via the API? Or are you asking about populating the data that would be displayed in a chart via the API?

Comment: I'm asking about creating items in the dashboard via the API.

Comment: +1 for being able to be able to create CloudWatch dashboards programmatically or via CLI. I deploy other AWS assets this way, I don't see why dashboards should be any different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted AWS technical support. This is a snippet of the response:

> Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment... I went ahead and created a feature request to our CloudWatch team...

The answer is "No", this is not possible at this time.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is now out of date, please see the other answer about using CloudFormation to codify CloudWatch Dashboards.  For historical purposes here is my original reply:  The accepted answer is effectively "no".  However it may be worth noting that if you were to create a graph through the web interface and inspect the URL that is generated for you through the "Copy URL" button, you can see the patterns it uses and you could come up with your own URL.  Note that when you click the "Copy URL" button in the CloudWatch web interface, it doesn't do anything special on its backend other than programmatically generate a URL for you based on your currently selected options.  Therefore in a way this offers you a way to generate your own graphs programmatically, albeit in a rather unintuitive and messy way since as far as I can tell there isn't a published specification for how those URLs are assembled and you must figure it out on your own through trial and error.

Comment: This is not possible with CloudWatch Dashboards, only on the Metrics.

Answer (score 5):

As of 05 Jul 2017 it is possible: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-api-cloudformation-support-for-amazon-cloudwatch-dashboards/

Comment: This is what I was looking for in my original question. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

The short answer is yes. CloudWatch has support for Custom Metrics data i.e. either application specific data which you can evaluate and send to CloudWatch or real-time data like [to use example stated by Amazon] Temperature of your data center.

You can use CloudWatch to represent any data, to simplify CloudWatch is just a Statistics Repository which would keep your data for 14 days.

Once you upload your data, they would appear as custom metrics in the CloudWatch Page. You can navigate and use the provided custom metric to represent your data in the CloudWatch Dashboard.